# file_get_contents() Timeout in php

Tags: javascript, php, timeout, file-get-contents

I know php doesn't give timeout option since it is running from server side. But my logic needs timeout. Please solve this case

**My PHP:** login.php :-

```
$forms_values = $_POST;
$url = "http://sample.com/sample?params=$forms_values";
$resp = file_get_contents($url);
// It takes much time if sample.com is down.
// so need to set time out here.
$response = json_decode($resp, true);
....
....
if ($response["auth"] == "yes"){
   header("index.php");
}
```

**my html** index.html :-

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="clientLogin">
    <div>
        <input id="username" placeholder="Email or Username" type="text" name="luser" size="30" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="passwd" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="lpasswd" size="30" value="">
    </div>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//This is not working. and obviously delay will happen in server code 
//and i cant get it in client side 

$(window).load(function () {
     var submit = false;
     $("#clientLogin").submit(function(e) {
         alert("me after 1000 mili seconds");
          setTimeout(function(){
              alert("me after 1000 mili seconds");
              submit = true;
              $("#clientLogin").submit(); // if you want            
          }, 15000);
          if(!submit)
              e.preventDefault();
     });
};
</script>
```

This javascript is not working. and obviously delay will happen in server code and i cannot watch it from client side.

so this is what i want. need to terminate submission process (from submit to rendering next page) if my `file_get_contents()` function is not responding for long.

**Note**:
Please dont ask me to use curl, Because i am instructed to not use curl. 
and i cant get it in client side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value for a timeout in file_get_contents() is 60 seconds.
You can change this value through the default_socket_timeout setting.
It's also doable in your code:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 2); // 2 seconds
```

Comment: what this my `file_get_contents()` will return if it times out. Because i need to send some error message to client back.

Comment: it should return FALSE.
use the === operator to compare the return value

Comment: It works. Thanks for `ini_set()`. and setting `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 60);` back next to my warning message will make it default (60 sec) rite?

Comment: Yes. If you want to reset it thats how you would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Place the code the beginning of your script

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 30); // 30 seconds
```

by default it is set to 60 seconds .

Comment: Thanks for your answer i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider using  [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) .

It provides the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT parameter to specify the amount of time to wait while trying to establish a connection.

Comment: It okey and `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 2);` one healped. Thanks for your answer i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> set_time_limit() does run globally, but it can be reset locally.

Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.

When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.
I've not tested it, but you may be able to set it locally, resetting when you leave the

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);  // global setting

function doStuff()
{
    set_time_limit(10);   // limit this function
    //  stuff
    set_time_limit(10);   // give ourselves another 10 seconds if we want
    //  stuff
    set_time_limit(0);    // the rest of the file can run forever
}

// ....
sleep(900);
// ....
doStuff();  // only has 10 secs to run
// ....
sleep(900);
// ....
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't receive the content in 5 seconds, `$resp` will be empty

```php
$ctx = stream_context_create(['http'=> ['timeout' => 5]]); // 5 seconds
$resp = file_get_contents($url,null,$ctx);
```